# jq bash Adding a json field to a json file

Tags: json, bash, jq

i'm stuck on jq input problem. I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{
    "main_object": {
        "child1": ["banana", "apple", "orange"]
    }
}
```

I need to add another child object and rewrite this file, the problem is that this child object needs to be generated dynamically. so i'm doing this:

```
added_string=$(printf '.main_object += {%s: %s}' "$child_name" "$fruits")
```

Then I wrote this line, which worked well on my mac shell:

```
edited_json=$(cat $json_variable_file | jq $added_string)
```

When i tried to run all of this from a bash script i got this error:

jq: error: Could not open file +=: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file {"child2":: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file ["orange","potato","watermelon"]}: No such file or directory

So I tried many things so far, most of them still give me the same error, also tried doing this:

```
edited_json=$(cat $json_variable_file | jq <<< $added_string)
```

The error i got is this:
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 23

Really appreciate your time, the weird thing here is that it works completely fine, generating the needed json on my zsh but it does not work on bash.

Comment: The bash problem is the unquoted variable: `jq "$added_string"` -- this is one main area where zsh breaks away from POSIX shell syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash` and `zsh`:

```
child_name="child2"
fruits='["orange","potato","watermelon"]'

added_string=$(printf '.main_object += {%s: %s}' "$child_name" "$fruits")
cat file | jq "$added_string"  # quotes are important
```

Output:

```
{
  "main_object": {
    "child1": [
      "banana",
      "apple",
      "orange"
    ],
    "child2": [
      "orange",
      "potato",
      "watermelon"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `jq "$added_string" < file.json` Works with `zsh` without the `cat`

Comment: @Jetchisel: I assume that it also works without `<`.

Comment: Indeed looks like it. `jq` ftw! :)